# challenge error shows null after failed attempt to login

Tags: ios, ios7, challenge-response

This is a by the book example of REST/Webservice authentication in iOS.

My password is wrong, and I get to the second part of else condition, which is correct behaviour.

However `[error localizedDescription]` shows null.  I was expecting an error to be shown here. Any idea what I am missing?

I get this:

> Can't authenticate: (null)

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential;

        newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[FTKeychain loadValueForKey:IOS_USER_EMAIL]
                                                   password:[FTKeychain loadValueForKey:IOS_USER_PASSWORD]
                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        // inform the user that the user name and password
        // in the preferences are incorrect
        // Why did I fail?
        NSError *error = [challenge error];
        NSLog(@"Can't authenticate: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        // why is error localizedDescription null ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not returning an error. See the class description for the challenge where it states:

> Discussion This method returns nil if the protocol doesn’t use errors
>   to indicate an authentication failure.

I suggest logging as the whole object and if the description is sparse then other properties too.